# Loop swf after certain number of seconds

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am creating a flash animation using flashEFF animation components.  The animation isn't looping like it's supposed to be at the end of the animation, so I would like to hard-code a replay after 20 seconds.  How would I use AS3 to loop reset to the beginning after 30 seconds?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it like this after identifying  the MovieClip instance.

```
movie.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, function (event:Event) {
  if(movie.currentFrame == 300){  // if 300 is the last frame
        movie.gotoAndPlay(1);
    }
});
```

Or if you want a time out of 30s

```
setTimeout(function(){
    movie.gotoAndPlay(1);
}, 30000);
```

Comment: Might I suggest not using an anonymous function in an eventlistener in flash?

Comment: I think adobe push the `Timer` class as the "proper" way, over `setTimeout/setInterval`, not sure if it's considered deprecated tho